# is this possible to autoResizing height textare without JS ? using only CSS code?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

we can easily Autoresizing textarea using JS or other language.. is this possible to resize textarea using CSS ?

Comment: Its impossible until you show us some codes.

Comment: Maybe transitions can help

Comment: Without javascript you can't. You need to auto resize textarea on keyup event.http://jsonwrapper.com/

Comment: On textarea - pretty sure you can't. You can make an editable div autogrow with the contenteditable (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) attribute. However, you can't submit a contenteditable field without JavaScript, so you'll need JavaScript either way.

Comment: "based on its content length/height" - that is not, what op asked @René.

Comment: @Huelfe You might be right, I assumed something. Did a rollback of my edits. Maybe the author can explain his question a bit more so we don't have to assume anything. Although I still think he means growing on content length...